# Parameter passing and method calling

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a question about parameter passing. In this example methodTwo wants to call methodOne but only use the x, and y values and not the Color color. When I try to do this i get a error in Eclipse "the method methodOne(double x, double y, Color color) in the type 'example class name' is not applicable for the arguments (double, double))"
 Can methodTwo not call another methodOne if it does not use exactly all of the arguments of methodOne?

```
private void methodOne (double x, double y, Color color){
   statements...;
  }

private void methodTwo (x, y ){
  methodOne(x, y);
  statements...;
}
```

Comment: What is this  ? method 1(x, y); Is this a valid method.Please correct it.

Comment: @JDeveloper i realized my mistake and I edited it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use all the parameter to call method1. (Order of parameters and type of parameter are also important)

If you do not have third parameter you can use method1 as

```
private void methodTwo (x, y ){
  method 1(x, y, null);
  statements...;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code as below :-

```
  private void methodTwo (x, y ){
      methodOne(x, y);  //Now this will show error , because parameter not matching
      statements...;
    }
```

If  you do not want to pass 3rd parameter then it will show error. So, you have to pass 3rd parameter and for your purpose  you can pass `null` , being you are not using the 3rd parameter in the function definition.

Ist Solution :-

```
private void methodTwo (x, y ){
      methodOne(x, y,null); 
      //statements...;
    }
```

2nd solution you can overload this `methodOne` with 2 parameter like below :-

```
private void methodOne(double x, double y, Color color){
   //statements... same job;
  }

private void methodOne(double x, double y){
   //statements...same job;
  }
```

Now when you call the `methodOne` method with 2 parameter as follow :-

```
private void methodTwo (x, y ){
  methodOne(x,y); // Now the overloaded method will call
  //statements...;
}
```

Comment: nice info thanks. Are there certain advantages or disadvantages of choosing one way to do it over the other?

Comment: Yes @JessicaM. basically when you are choosing method overloading at that time your application or purpose must be multiple result.May be the output of all overloaded methods are vary little bit. But for  your purpose you should use 1st options.Happy voteing :)

Answer (score 0):

Method names have to be one word. You also need to provide the last parameter.

```
private void method1 (double x, double y, Color color){
   statements...;
  }

private void method2 (x, y ){
  method1(x, y, someColorOrNull);
  statements...;
}
```

From the JLS, section 3.8 "Identifiers":

> An identifier is an unlimited-length sequence of Java letters and Java
>   digits, the first of which must be a Java letter.
>
> ```
> Identifier:
>     IdentifierChars but not a Keyword or BooleanLiteral or NullLiteral
>
> IdentifierChars:
>     JavaLetter
>     IdentifierChars JavaLetterOrDigit
>
> JavaLetter:
>     any Unicode character that is a Java letter (see below)
>
> JavaLetterOrDigit:
>     any Unicode character that is a Java letter-or-digit (see below)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

> Can method 2 not call another method 1 if it does not use exactly all of the arguments of method 1?

it can but you have to override method 1 like this:

```
    private void method 1 (double x, double y, Color color){
       statements...;
      }

    private void method 1 (double x, double y){
       statements...;
      }

    private void method 2 (x, y ){
      method 1(x, y);
      statements...;
    }
```